# Crossdomain Javascript Embed, not working in IE versions

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-domain

I have a embeddable Javascript (Cannot use jQuery) Event Widget for our Chamber of Commerce:

http://www.cvchamber.ca/calendar-widget/

Essentially you copy/paste this into your site:

```
<!--
CV Chamber of Commerce Event Widget
Copy and paste where you want the calendar to appear.
-->
<div id="event-widget"></div>
<script src="http://goo.gl/jxLBvi"></script>
```

The script itself is this:

```
function callback(jsondata){
    document.getElementById('event-widget').innerHTML = jsondata.html ;
}
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://www.cvchamber.ca/wpcvcc/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_events&count=5&callback=callback';
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

The URL http://www.cvchamber.ca/wpcvcc/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_events&count=5&callback=callback simply retrieves some HTML for placement inside the div.

It works in all browsers except for IE, what can/should I be doing to make this compatible?

Comment: First we need to know what about said html or javascript isn't compatible. How far is it getting? are there any errors in the console? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: When i try it i get `"Script from http://www.cvchamber.ca/wpcvcc/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_events&count=5&callback=callback&format=xml was blocked due to mime type mismatch"` shouldn't your type be text/javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE doesn't recognize `"application/json"` as executable javascript, so it rejects the script. The server should instead be returning with the contentType set to `"text/javascript"` for JSONP requests.

Comment: Thanks, nice easy fix. Kinda embarrassed I couldn't see it :)

Comment: No problem, it's not a very common mistake. Usually you see it in the form of `<script type="application/javascript">` which IE also doesn't recognize. (older ie, haven't tried that since IE9)